# Properties.Settings will not be saved

Tags: c#, application-settings

I'm trying to save two user values (SliderWidth and SliderHeight). I want to do this with the Visual Studio option settings.

[image: The Visual Studio option settings]

When I debug this with this code:

```
    public void Test(int value)
    {
        Properties.Settings settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
        settings.SliderWidth = value;
        settings.Save();
    }
```

The values ​​do not change  (after the program ended).

What's wrong?

Comment: User settings are saved in the user.config file, so you won't observe the changes by looking at the app.config file, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez hm thanks, but where exactly do I find the file then? in my bin\debug folder it is not

Comment: it is actually hidden somewhere in the %appdata% folder. You might search and find a user.config in a folder specific to your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely works.  Try this:

```
public void Test(int value)
{
    Properties.Settings settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    MessageBox.Show("Last SliderWidth = " + settings.SliderWidth.ToString());

    settings.SliderWidth = value;
    settings.Save();
}
```

But the saved value won't be reflected in the Designer window you are showing in your screen shot.  Those are the initial default values.

Comment: Lars: So, if I am debugging my app, I will ONLY see the initial values hard coded into my Settings page (like shown in the OP's screenshot). But, when I deploy my application it will pull and store the User's settings. Correct?

Comment: @jp2code Not quite (if I understand you correctly).  When you run your program in design mode, it will get the value from the settings file, but if there is no value, *then* it will retrieve the default value that was set in that setting form pictured above.

Comment: My app is supposed to be storing the last opened form (enumerated as an integer) and the form's Top, Left, Width, and Height. After storing the values, I call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` but nothing changes when I open the app back up to read in the values.

Comment: @jp2code Just a guess, but make sure the scope is set to `User`, otherwise, you would have to post a question duplicating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your AssemblyInfo.cs has a * in the Assembly version it resets this file each time. Try hard coding that last number. Clean and rebuild all and it should work fine.